# I have a problem reading .msagl files using AutomaticGraphLayout.Drawing Version="1.1.12"

Tags: c#, msagl

I have a problem reading .msagl files using `AutomaticGraphLayout.Drawing` version 1.1.12, but it works when I use `Microsoft.Msagl.Drawing` version  1.1.6. This is a problem as I would like to use the `Graph` object from the newer version, but I dont know how to convert from the `Graph` object in version 1.1.6 where reading works to version 1.1.12 that I would like to have my `Graph` element as.

Does anyone know how to convert from one to the other?

I have tried to use the `.Read(fileName)` method from version 1.1.12, but it gives me an `System.ArgumentException`:

> Requested value "Default" was not found.

When I run the exact same code using the older version it works.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.